On the completion of Borel $\sigma-$algebra in $R^2$
I'm re-asking a question answered from 7 years ago, whose answer I think is partly incorrect. The question is as follows:
Question:
Let $B_{2}$ be the Borel-$\sigma$ algebra on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, that is, the smallest $\sigma-$algebra that contains all open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Let $B_{1}$ be the usual Borel-$\sigma$ algebra on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $B_1 \times B_1$ be the product $\sigma-$algebra, generated by the "measurable rectangles" $I_1 \times I_2$ (where $(I_i)_i \subset B_1)$.
(1) Is $B_{2}$ equal to $B_{1}\times B_{1}$? Prove or Disprove.
(2) Let $m_2$ be the 2-dimensional Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Are the completions of $B_{2}$ and $B_{1}\times B_{1}$ identical with respect to this measure? Prove or Disprove.
My Doubt:
I understand why the answer to (1) is true. However, I'm confused about (2) in the context of (1) being true + a previous post suggesting a different answer, as follows:
For (2), we ask whether $\overline{B_2} = \overline{B_1 \times B_1}$. In response to this, the previous post includes a link to another answer about why $L_2 \ne L_1 \times L_1$. Seeing this, I thought they're suggesting that $L_1 \times L_1 = \overline{B_1 \times B_1}$, so that by this other result, $\overline{B_2} = L_2 \ne L_1 \times L_1 = \overline{B_1 \times B_1}$.
I don't think this is true, however: if $B_2 = B_1 \times B_1$, i.e., the measurable sets are the same, and then we consider their completion wrt. the same measure $m_2$, then shouldn't their completions be the same, i.e., $\overline{B_2} = \overline{B_1 \times B_1}$?

You're right. The linked answer to question (2) is incorrect, or at least irrelevant.

Since $B_2 = B_1 \times B_1$ and the measure is the same, it is immediate that
$\overline{B_2} = \overline{B_1 \times B_1}$.
Attention: $L_1 \times L_1 \not=  \overline{B_1 \times B_1}$. In fact, $L_1 \times L_1 = \overline{B_1}  \times \overline{B_1}$. The right conclusion is
$$\overline{B_1 \times B_1} = \overline{B_2} = L_2 \not= L_1 \times L_1 = \overline{B_1}  \times \overline{B_1}$$

But also, the formulation of (2) in the linked question does not mention which measures we are completing with respect to. The question OP meant to ask probably involved the completions with respect to different measures, i.e. $m_2$ vs. $m_1 \times m_1$.

In the formulation of (2) in the linked question they, by mistake, replace the question whether $\overline{B_2} = \overline{B_1 \times B_1}$, by the different question whether $\overline{B_2} =\overline{B_1}  \times \overline{B_1}$.  Note that the right answers to those similar questions are very different:  $\overline{B_2} = \overline{B_1 \times B_1}$  and $\overline{B_2} \not= \overline{B_1}  \times \overline{B_1}$.

The product sigma algebra is usually denoted $B_1 \otimes B_1$ to emphasize that this is not the same as a product of two sets.  The latex for $\otimes$ is "backslash otimes."
